# Radio buttons changing class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

i have and issue with jQuery code for checking which one of the radio buttons is checked and then to change the color to some of them.Also i want to disable buttons after one of them is pressed. My problem i that when i check for example 'A' all the answers becoming red and not 'A' to become green and all the others red.

```js
  $(function() {
    $('.AncientQ11 [type="radio"]').on('change', function() {

      $(document.getElementById("AncientQ1Ans1"))
        .prev().addClass('green')
        .siblings().addClass('red');

      document.getElementById("AncientQ1Ans1").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("AncientQ1Ans2").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("AncientQ1Ans3").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("AncientQ1Ans4").disabled = true;
    });
  });
```

```css
.red {color: red;}
.black {color: black;}
.green{color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="AncientQ11">
  <label for="AncientQ1Ans1">A</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="AncientQ1Ans1" name="AncientQ1">

  <label for="AncientQ1Ans2">B</label><br>
  <!--Solution-->
  <input type="radio" id="AncientQ1Ans2" name="AncientQ1">

  <label for="AncientQ1Ans3">C</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="AncientQ1" id="AncientQ1Ans3">


  <label for="AncientQ1Ans4">D</label>
  <input type="radio" name="AncientQ1" id="AncientQ1Ans4">
</div>
```

Comment: off topic: `$(document.getElementById("AncientQ1Ans1"))` -> `$("#AncientQ1Ans1")`

Comment: How does your js/html know that Q1Ans1 is the correct answer?  Are you hardcoding it in to the js?

Comment: Your issue is the "hidden" `<br/>` at between the label and the radio - it became evident when I converted your code to a snippet and ran it.   checkbox.prev = br, not the label.   The  cheap-/quick-fix is to change `.prev()` to `.prev().prev()` - the better solution would be to fix your layout - or, even better, use `$("label[for=AncientQ1Ans1").addClass("green")...`

Comment: Yes.I have wirite the same code for any question, but with different id.

Comment: Oh ok, i didnt know that. I have delete </br> and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `br` to use `div` with `display:block;` resolve your problem.

But after that if I select B,C or D solution, only the A is green. It's because you need to use `$(this)` to get the current element.

And I rewrite some parts to correspond to JQuery syntax like @freedomn-m suggests.

```js
  $(function() {
    $('.AncientQ11 [type="radio"]').on('change', function() {

      $(this).prev().addClass('green').siblings().addClass('red');

      $("#AncientQ1Ans1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $("#AncientQ1Ans2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $("#AncientQ1Ans3").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $("#AncientQ1Ans4").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
  });
```

```css
.red {color: red;}
.black {color: black;}
.green{color:green;}

.AncientQ11 > div{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="AncientQ11">
<div>
  <label for="AncientQ1Ans1">A</label>
  <input type="radio" id="AncientQ1Ans1" name="AncientQ1">
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="AncientQ1Ans2">B</label>
  <input type="radio" id="AncientQ1Ans2" name="AncientQ1">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="AncientQ1Ans3">C</label>
  <input type="radio" name="AncientQ1" id="AncientQ1Ans3">

</div>
<div>
  <label for="AncientQ1Ans4">D</label>
  <input type="radio" name="AncientQ1" id="AncientQ1Ans4">
  </div>
</div>
```